# Vb.Net Weight Scale Reading

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, scale, trim

Good evening everyone, I've been developing an app to read balances through serial port for a long time, after a long time just trying to read the data, I happily got the results, but the data is not synchronized, it takes an indefinite time to change the weight and when processing the data has the process of removing unwanted characters because the scale sends the data as follows: `ww0000.00kg`, after some changes I managed to make it change to `00.00kg`. The weight has to sync in real time:
It should work in the following way, when placing a weight the scale must be its value eg `13.75kg` and print and then remove the weight and return to normal (`00.00kg`) in less than 3 seconds.

Code:

```
Dim decWeightReading As Decimal, strScaleCommand As String
    Dim strSerialData As String
    Dim strSerialDataNew As String
    Dim strFirstData As String
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim diffDate As TimeSpan    
    Dim initRunning As Integer
    Dim IntWeightReading As Integer
    Dim DecWeightReadingLast As Decimal
    Dim datetime1 As Date, datetime2 As Date
```

Form Load:

```
Private Sub Menufrm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
```

TickTimer:

```
Private Sub TickTimer2()
    decWeightReading = CDec("0.000")
    strScaleCommand = "IP" + vbCrLf
    strFirstData = ""
    SerialPort1.WriteLine(strScaleCommand)
    strSerialData = SerialPort1.ReadLine
    strSerialDataNew = ""
    cnt = 0
    Do Until cnt = 10
        SerialPort1.WriteLine(strScaleCommand)
        strSerialDataNew = SerialPort1.ReadLine
        If strSerialDataNew = strSerialData Then
            cnt = cnt + 1
        Else
            strSerialData = strSerialDataNew
            strSerialDataNew = ""
            cnt = 0
        End If
        datetime2 = DateTime.Now
        diffDate = datetime2.Subtract(datetime1)
    Loop

End Sub
```

Time Tick and Trim the ww00:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
TickTimer2()
Dim header As String = strSerialData
strSerialData = (header)
Weight.Text = (strSerialData)
strSerialData.Trim({"w"c, "w"c, "0"c})
Weight.Text = (header.Trim({"w"c, "w"c, "0"c}))
```

End Sub

And another difficulty I'm facing is that when reading the data from the balance to print in the TextBox the process gets very slow, it's even difficult to click a button or see the list of values in a ComboBox.

If anyone have any help I would appreciate it

Comment: These are C# articles, but they will be helpful. [Serial Comms in C# for Beginners](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/678025/Serial-Comms-in-Csharp-for-Beginners), [Communicating With Serial Port In C#](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/eclipsed4utoo/communicating-with-serial-port-in-C-Sharp/)

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find anything related to my problem. I can already read the balance data.

Comment: I introduced it as an example of event-driven serial port reading that is not a software loop and writing the received result from the sub thread to the TextBox. If you're doing well with the I/O process and the only problem is that it takes time, you'll have to experiment and find out where the bottleneck is.

Comment: What is the scale make and model? I'm not quite sure what you mean by the following: "The weight has to sync in real time: It should work in the following way, when placing a weight the scale must be its value eg 13.75kg and print and then remove the weight and return to normal (00.00kg) in less than 3 seconds." What do you mean by "print"? Display the value in a Textbox? Are you removing the object from the scale or attempting to zero it out with the object still on the scale? Why are you looping 10 times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following shows how to read data using SerialPort - it subscribes to the DataReceived event. In VB.NET there are two different options to subscribe to an event.

**Option 1** (WithEvents)

```
Private WithEvents Port As SerialPort = Nothing

Public Function Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600) As String
    
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    If Port Is Nothing Then

        'create new instance
        Port = New SerialPort(comPort)

    End If
                   ...

    Return result

End Function
```

To subscribe to the Port.DataReceived event:

```
Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles Port.DataReceived

End Sub
```

**Option 2** (AddHandler)

```
Private Port As SerialPort = Nothing

Public Function Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600) As String
    
    Dim result As String = String.Empty

    If Port Is Nothing Then

        'create new instance
        Port = New SerialPort(comPort)

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler Port.DataReceived, AddressOf Port_DataReceived
        AddHandler Port.ErrorReceived, AddressOf Port_ErrorReceived

    End If
                   ...

    Return result

End Function
```

To subscribe to the Port.DataReceived event:

```
Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Below are the steps to create a new Windows Forms (WinForms) project that uses SerialPort to read data along with the necessary code.

**Create a WinForms project**

**VS 2017**:

- Open Visual Studio
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- Expand **Installed**
- Expand **Visual Basic**
- Click **Windows Desktop**
- Select **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Specify project name (name: ReadSerialPort)
- Click **OK**

**VS 2019**:

- Open Visual Studio
- Click **Continue without code**
- Click **File**
- Select **New**
- Select **Project**
- **Visual Basic Windows Desktop**
- Click **Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)**
- Click **Next**
- Specify project name (name: ReadSerialPort)
- Click **Create**

**Note:** From this point forward, the process is the same for both VS 2017 and VS 2019.

Add some controls to Form1

[image]

**Open Properties Window**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Properties Window**

**Open Solution Explorer**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**
- In Solution Explorer, double-click **Form1.vb** to open the designer.

**Add "Connect" button to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **Button**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form
- In Properties Window, for "button1", set **(name)**: btnConnect; set **Text**: Connect
- In Properties Window, click [image] (Events). Double-click **Click** to add event handler to Form1.vb

**Add "Disconnect" button to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **Button**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form
- In Properties Window, for "button1", set **(name)**: btnDisconnect; set **Text**: Disconnect
- In Properties Window, click [image] (Events). Double-click **Click** to add event handler to Form1.vb

**Add TextBox to Form1**

- In VS menu, select **View**
- Select **Toolbox**
- Select **TextBox**
- Click on Form1 to add the button to the form

**Add "Load" event handler to Form1**

- In Properties Window, for "Form1"", click [image] (Events). Double-click **Load** to add event handler to Form1.vb

**Add "FormClosing" event handler to Form1**

- In Properties Window, for "Form1"", click [image] (Events). Double-click **FormClosing** to add event handler to Form1.vb

**Add class**: HelperSerialPort

- On VS menu, select **Project**
- Select **Add Class** (name: HelperSerialPort.vb)

**Option 1** (WithEvents)

**HelperSerialPort.vb**

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Enum PortBaudRate As Integer
    Baud1200 = 1200
    Baud2400 = 2400
    Baud4800 = 4800
    Baud9600 = 9600
    Baud14400 = 14400
    Baud19200 = 19200
    Baud28800 = 28800
    Baud38400 = 38400
    Baud56000 = 56000
    Baud76800 = 76800
    Baud115200 = 115200

End Enum

Public Class HelperSerialPort
    Implements IDisposable

    Private WithEvents Port As SerialPort = Nothing

    'events that can be subscribed to
    Public Event DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal data As String)
    Public Event ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal errMsg As String)

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600) As String
        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty
        Dim portName As String = String.Empty
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(comPort) Then
            errMsg = "COM port not selected"
            Throw New Exception(errMsg)
        End If

        Try
            If Port Is Nothing Then

                'create new instance
                Port = New SerialPort(comPort)

            End If

            If Not Port.IsOpen Then

                'set properties
                Port.BaudRate = baudRate
                Port.Handshake = Handshake.None

                'if parity is even or odd, then set DataBits = 7
                'if parity is none, set DataBits = 8
                Port.Parity = Parity.Even 'Even, None, Odd 
                Port.DataBits = 7

                Port.StopBits = StopBits.One
                Port.ReadTimeout = 200
                Port.WriteTimeout = 50
                Port.DtrEnable = True 'enable Data Terminal Ready
                Port.RtsEnable = True 'enable Request to Send

                'open port
                Port.Open()

                result = "Status: Connected"
            Else
                result = "Status: Already Connected"
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            errMsg = "Error: " & ex.Message
            result = errMsg 'set value
            Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Debug.WriteLine(result)

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Sub Disconnect()
        Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
        If Port IsNot Nothing Then

            Port.Dispose()
            Port = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles Port.DataReceived
        'read SerialPort data
        Dim data As String = String.Empty

        data = Port.ReadExisting()
        'data = Port.ReadLine

        Debug.WriteLine("Data: " & data)

        'raise event
        RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Port_ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs) Handles Port.ErrorReceived
        Dim errMsg As String = e.EventType.ToString()

        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " & errMsg)

        'raise event
        RaiseEvent ErrorReceived(Me, errMsg)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToSerialPort(ByVal data As String)
        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty

        Try
            If Port.IsOpen Then

                'convert string to Byte array
                Dim hexArr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                For Each hexVal As Byte In hexArr

                    'convert byte to byte array
                    Dim tempArr As Byte() = New Byte() {hexVal}

                    'write 
                    Port.Write(tempArr, 0, 1)

                    'add 1 ms delay before writing next byte
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
                Next
            Else
                errMsg = "Error: Port is not open. Please open the connection and try again."
                Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
                Throw New Exception(errMsg)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            errMsg = "Error: " & ex.Message
            Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Modify Form1.vb code**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **View Code**

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents helper As HelperSerialPort = New HelperSerialPort

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'get port names
        For Each portName In SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            Debug.WriteLine("portName: " & portName)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600)
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            Debug.WriteLine("comPort: " & comPort & " baudRate: " & baudRate.ToString())
            helper.Connect(comPort, baudRate)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Helper_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal data As String) Handles helper.DataReceived
        Debug.WriteLine("Data: " & data)

        'set value
        Dim tempData As String = data

        If tempData.StartsWith("ww") AndAlso tempData.EndsWith("kg") Then
            tempData = tempData.Substring(2, data.Length - 4)
        End If

        'If tempData.StartsWith("ww") Then
        'tempData = tempData.Substring(2)
        'End If

        'If tempData.EndsWith("kg") Then
        'tempData = tempData.Substring(0, tempData.IndexOf("kg"))
        'End If

        'set text in TextBox
        TextBox1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                              TextBox1.Text = tempData
                                              TextBox1.Refresh()
                                          End Sub))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Helper_ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal errMsg As String) Handles helper.ErrorReceived
        Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disconnect()
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            helper.Disconnect()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        Connect("COM1", PortBaudRate.Baud9600)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisconnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.Click
        Disconnect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        'dispose
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            helper.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Option 2** (AddHandler)

**HelperSerialPort.vb**

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Enum PortBaudRate As Integer
    Baud1200 = 1200
    Baud2400 = 2400
    Baud4800 = 4800
    Baud9600 = 9600
    Baud14400 = 14400
    Baud19200 = 19200
    Baud28800 = 28800
    Baud38400 = 38400
    Baud56000 = 56000
    Baud76800 = 76800
    Baud115200 = 115200

End Enum

Public Class HelperSerialPort
    Implements IDisposable

    Private Port As SerialPort = Nothing

    Public Event DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal data As String)
    Public Event ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal errMsg As String)

    Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Function Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600) As String
        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty
        Dim portName As String = String.Empty
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(comPort) Then
            errMsg = "COM port not selected"
            Throw New Exception(errMsg)
        End If


        Debug.WriteLine("comPort: " & comPort)

        Try
            If Port Is Nothing Then
                Debug.WriteLine("creating new instance of SerialPort")

                'create new instance
                Port = New SerialPort(comPort)

                'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
                AddHandler Port.DataReceived, AddressOf Port_DataReceived
                AddHandler Port.ErrorReceived, AddressOf Port_ErrorReceived

            End If

            If Not Port.IsOpen Then

                Debug.WriteLine("Port isn't open")

                'set properties
                Port.BaudRate = baudRate
                Port.Handshake = Handshake.None

                'if parity is even or odd, then set DataBits = 7
                'if parity is none, set DataBits = 8
                Port.Parity = Parity.Even 'Even, None, Odd 
                Port.DataBits = 7

                Port.StopBits = StopBits.One
                Port.ReadTimeout = 200
                Port.WriteTimeout = 50
                Port.DtrEnable = True 'enable Data Terminal Ready
                Port.RtsEnable = True 'enable Request to Send

                'open port
                Port.Open()

                result = "Status: Connected"
            Else
                result = "Status: Already Connected"
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            errMsg = "Error: " & ex.Message
            result = errMsg 'set value
            Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Debug.WriteLine(result)

        Return result
    End Function

    Public Sub Disconnect()
        Dispose()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.IDisposable.Dispose
        If Port IsNot Nothing Then

            'unsubscribe from events (remove event handlers)
            RemoveHandler Port.DataReceived, AddressOf Port_DataReceived
            RemoveHandler Port.ErrorReceived, AddressOf Port_ErrorReceived

            Port.Dispose()
            Port = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Port_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)
        'read SerialPort data
        Dim data As String = String.Empty

        data = Port.ReadExisting()
        'data = Port.ReadLine

        Debug.WriteLine("Data: " & data)

        'raise event
        RaiseEvent DataReceived(Me, data)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Port_ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs)
        Dim errMsg As String = e.EventType.ToString()

        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " & errMsg)

        'raise event
        RaiseEvent ErrorReceived(Me, errMsg)
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteToSerialPort(ByVal data As String)
        Dim errMsg As String = String.Empty

        Try
            If Port.IsOpen Then

                'convert string to Byte array
                Dim hexArr As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data)

                For Each hexVal As Byte In hexArr

                    'convert byte to byte array
                    Dim tempArr As Byte() = New Byte() {hexVal}

                    'write 
                    Port.Write(tempArr, 0, 1)

                    'add 1 ms delay before writing next byte
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1)
                Next
            Else
                errMsg = "Error: Port is not open. Please open the connection and try again."
                Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
                Throw New Exception(errMsg)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            errMsg = "Error: " & ex.Message
            Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

**Modify Form1.vb code**

- In Solution Explorer, right-click **Form1.vb**
- Select **View Code**

**Form1.vb**

```
Imports System.IO.Ports

Public Class Form1

    Private helper As HelperSerialPort = Nothing

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        'create new instance
        helper = New HelperSerialPort()

        'subscribe to events (add event handlers)
        AddHandler helper.DataReceived, AddressOf Helper_DataReceived
        AddHandler helper.ErrorReceived, AddressOf Helper_ErrorReceived

        'get port names
        For Each portName In SerialPort.GetPortNames()
            Debug.WriteLine("portName: " & portName)
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub Connect(ByVal comPort As String, ByVal Optional baudRate As PortBaudRate = PortBaudRate.Baud9600)
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            Debug.WriteLine("comPort: " & comPort & " baudRate: " & baudRate.ToString())
            helper.Connect(comPort, baudRate)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Helper_DataReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal data As String)
        Debug.WriteLine("Data: " & data)

        'set value
        Dim tempData As String = data

        If tempData.StartsWith("ww") AndAlso tempData.EndsWith("kg") Then
            tempData = tempData.Substring(2, data.Length - 4)
        End If

        'If tempData.StartsWith("ww") Then
        'tempData = tempData.Substring(2)
        'End If

        'If tempData.EndsWith("kg") Then
        'tempData = tempData.Substring(0, tempData.IndexOf("kg"))
        'End If

        'set text in TextBox
        TextBox1.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(Sub()
                                              TextBox1.Text = tempData
                                              TextBox1.Refresh()
                                          End Sub))

    End Sub

    Private Sub Helper_ErrorReceived(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal errMsg As String)
        Debug.WriteLine(errMsg)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Disconnect()
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            helper.Disconnect()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnConnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnConnect.Click
        Connect("COM1", PortBaudRate.Baud9600)
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDisconnect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisconnect.Click
        Disconnect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        'dispose
        If helper IsNot Nothing Then
            helper.Dispose()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

**Resources**:

- [What does 'InvokeRequired' and 'Invoke' mean in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662905/what-does-invokerequired-and-invoke-mean-in-net)

Comment: If interested, the following post shows how to read data using SerialPort in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65957066/serial-to-usb-cable-from-a-scale-to-pc-some-values-are-just-question-marks/65971845#65971845 .

Comment: Thanks, can I have your Email, Skype, Telegram or Whatsapp?