# problem with my visual basic weighting scale reader

Tags: vb.net

i have written a program i visual basic which is supposed to read weight from a weighting scale into a label through serial(rs-232) connection, but for some reason it just doesnt read the weight?

someone please help me out

here's what i've done:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub BtnDiscon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnDiscon.Click
        BtnDiscon.Enabled = False
        BtnDiscon.SendToBack()

        Timer1.Stop()

        SerialPort1.Close()

        BtnCon.Enabled = True
        BtnCon.BringToFront()

    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCon_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnCon.Click
        BtnCon.Enabled = False
        BtnCon.SendToBack()

        SerialPort1.BaudRate = CmbBaud.SelectedItem
        SerialPort1.PortName = CmbScanPort.SelectedItem
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Timer1.Start()


        BtnDiscon.Enabled = True
        BtnDiscon.BringToFront()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.CenterToParent()
        BtnCon.Enabled = False
        BtnCon.BringToFront()

        BtnDiscon.Enabled = False
        BtnDiscon.SendToBack()

        CmbBaud.SelectedItem = "9600"
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnScanPort_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnScanPort.Click
        CmbScanPort.Items.Clear()
        Dim myPort As Array
        Dim i As Integer
        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        CmbScanPort.Items.AddRange(myPort)
        i = CmbScanPort.Items.Count
        i = i - i
        Try
            CmbScanPort.SelectedIndex = i

        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim result As DialogResult
            result = MessageBox.Show("not detected", "warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            CmbScanPort.Text = ""
            CmbScanPort.Items.Clear()
            Call Form1_Load(Me, e)
        End Try
        BtnCon.Enabled = True
        BtnCon.BringToFront()
        CmbScanPort.DroppedDown = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Try
            Dim i As Single = SerialPort1.ReadExisting
            Label2.Text = i.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

im using visual studio 2019.

Comment: Please don't use the VBA tag for VB.Net.

Comment: ok sorry bro i didnt know im new

Comment: Then go and read the guidance on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68332588/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/74895268/10024425