# Disable Winform from accessing UI across threads

Tags: visual-studio, winforms

During Winforms development, Visual Studio often reports an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Invalid inter-thread operation: Control 'xxxx' was accessed from a thread other than the thread that created it.

As we all know, the reason for this exception is that the thread that created the UI is not the same thread that is currently accessing the UI. In order to prevent thread insecurity, Winform throws an exception for this cross-thread access and prohibits this operation.

I want to use the InvokeRequired attribute to determine whether it is thread safe. But if this involves handles, it will be more difficult to deal with (forgive me for my limited level).

I would be very grateful if anyone could give me some advice or recommend some magical plug-ins.

Comment: Your question might be a duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the).

Comment: [Progress<T> class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not require the use of plug-ins. It is very common to access the UI across threads in WinForm. For example, if you perform some operation in a sub-window and want to update some status or data in the main window, cross-threads will appear if you are not careful. Exception when thread accesses UI. The Invoke method is widely used:

```
    private void Log(string log)
    {
        Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(log);
            textBox1.AppendText("\r\n");

        }));
    }
```

Comment: So is Invoke better to use than InvokeRequired?

Comment: @Helentyy It's not what you think. The function of Invokerequired is to determine whether to use Invoke. For details, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662905/what-does-invokerequired-and-invoke-mean-in-net

Comment: Thank you very much for your patient guidance